# Use a small amount of C++-level code from another package

Tags: c++, r

There is an R package that defines some handy functions for extracting files from zip archives into a `std::string` in C++.  I'd like to use those functions in my own packages, but I can't simply link to them because the header is not in the `inst/include` directory of the original package.

My question is based on my understanding that C++-level code isn't available outside a package unless the header is in `inst/include`.

To use the code, my options are:

1. Ask the package maintainer to move the C++ header file to the `inst/include` directory so that I can call it from my package with `linkingTo` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.
2. Copy and acknowledge the code, which means propagating the GPL-3 licence to my own package.
3. Copy and pointlessly alter the code to evade copyright.
4. Copy the code, which is about 20 lines, don't alter it, don't acknowledge it, and don't propagate the GPL-3 licence.
5. Create a separate, tiny package that makes the code I want available in `inst/include`, acknowledges the original author, and propogates the GPL-3 licence to itself (but not to my actual package, which simply `includes` it).

Are there any other options?  Have I misunderstood [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) or [Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf)?

**Clarification**: I do not at all condone options 3 and 4, which are, in my view, cheating.  Hence the question.  People reading the answers will now see that such things are regarded as cheating.  But they are things people consider when doing the 'right thing' is harder than a simple `Imports: package`, which is why I included them.

Comment: If the code you are talking about is under the GPL, rather than the LGPL, then your code has to be GPL as well even if you only `#include` stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these are good questions but not, I think, appropriate for StackOverflow ... I would recommend the [r-pkg-devel mailing list](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwit7_mUj9rNAhXC8YMKHarKB40QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstat.ethz.ch%2Fmailman%2Flistinfo%2Fr-package-devel&usg=AFQjCNGk9Y29V1XWfbHO-kMqn6BtOm990A&sig2=AlEC1hDoQDQauqPjwPL8pw) ...

Comment: Also, "pointlessly altering the code to evade copyright" is practically the definition of plagiarism. Further, given that you've now publicly mentioned this option, you'll have a hard time evading copyright without anyone noticing.

Comment: IANAL, but 3. and 4. sound quite fishy. 5. is probably not feasible either if your package working actually depends on the gpl code. Source: Got paid money to get rid of GPL dependency in proprietary code so it could be sold.

Comment: 6. ask the package maintainer to dual-license/let you use the code under a different license.

Comment: Btw, are you sure there are no more permissively licensed C++ or R libraries with the functionality you need?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the link to r-pkg-devel, I'll post there.

Comment: You will end up linking with R so the aggregate is _always_ GPL licensed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only viable options are options 1 and 2.

Option 1 works provided the R maintainers are willing to give you the code *under a license other than the GPL*.  This of course implies that you are going to link only against that dual-licensed code, not against all of R.

Option 2 works if you are willing to use the GPL for your code and all your code which links to that code.

Option 3 is the very definition of plagiarism, and simply *not* an option.

Option 4 is fishy, unethical, and also a bit difficult to achieve now that you've publicly announced that option.

Option 5 does not work since the GPL applies to your separate package as well, and by extension also applies to all code using that package.

Comment: Good answer, and well put.

Comment: If I understand Dirk correctly, even Option 1 doesn't work, because the GPL is propagated from R anyway.

Comment: @nacnudus When the maintainers make the _relevant_ part of the code, which OP is interested in, available under a different license, I of course mean to imply that the OP will only link against _that_ code, not all of R. But it's a good point to clarify. Updated my answer

Comment: @nacnudus The key here is that the  *aggregate* of your code + R is under GPL; your code on its own isn’t necessarily. The exact consequences are complicated, have not been tested in court, and people in the OSS community disagree about them. However, given that R package descriptions explicitly mention a license, we can assume that it was the intention of the R authors to allow licenses other than GPL for packages.